# Accidentrally spent from unconfirmed transaction

Tags: transactions, unconfirmed-transactions, exchanges

I accidentally spent btc from an unconfirmed transaction.
Is it likely to confirm at a later date or is it just kinda stuck?
Ive tried searching for answers but I'm seeing conflicting information relating to this.

Comment: I wonder if your tx has been accepted at all - did you get a tx ID? Something that we could look up? If so, when the unconfirmed tx gets confirmed, and your tx is in the mempool, it will also go through. But I'd like to know if there is an tx ID...

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with spending unconfirmed outputs.  Bitcoin core will happily spend its own unconfirmed outputs, though it does prefer not to if it has a choice.

Your transaction can't confirm until its parent does, but otherwise it's treated like any other transaction.

If the parent paid a low feerate and will take a while to confirm then you could be waiting a bit, unless your feerate was high enough to make up for it.

If the unconfirmed parent was created by someone else and they successfully double-spend it, then your child transaction will be invalidated. Otherwise, assuming that doesn't happen and the feerates are sensible it'll confirm fine.

Answer (score -1):

If the transaction still have not been confirmed you can spend your BTC again and maybe send them to an address of your own with an higher fee for making it more likely to be confirmed first

Comment: Your answer sounds a lot like "send it again", which if followed can result in funds loss.